# Why doesn't Vim show number lines after editing .vimrc

Tags: vim

I have edited my .vimrc file to include the following line:

```
set number
```

I've saved the file and closed out vim entirely and when reopening files theres still no line numbers.

Here's the entire file which is located at */usr/share/vim/vimrc*

```
" Configuration file for vim
set modelines=0     " CVE-2007-2438

" Normally we use vim-extensions. If you want true vi-compatibility
" remove change the following statements
set nocompatible    " Use Vim defaults instead of 100% vi compatibility
set backspace=2     " more powerful backspacing

" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "crontab -e"
au BufWrite /private/tmp/crontab.* set nowritebackup
" Don't write backup file if vim is being called by "chpass"
au BufWrite /private/etc/pw.* set nowritebackup

set number
```

Comment: Try editing `~/.vimrc` instead

Comment: ^^ A local .vimrc in your home directory would entirely supercede the system default in /usr/share (you should make changes in ~/.vimrc anyway -  start by copying in the system vimrc if you don't have one already)

Comment: @ExplosionPills I apologize for my ignorance but what does "~/" mean?

Comment: type `:ver` in your vim. It'll show you which vimrc files are sourced.

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex, `~/` is your home directory.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, `$HOME` or `~`, their are the shorthand equivalent of the path for your *home* folder, as in Linux is `/home/your_name` or OSX is in `/Users/your_name`

Comment: Use `:verbose set number?` to see where it was last set from.

Comment: Amadan, I'd say that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After you edited your vimrc file(either the one of system default or the one in your home directory), you should use source command as followings to read it in and make those configurations valid on current session.

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```

or

```
:source  /usr/share/vim/vimrc
```